# Why can't I display alert if text box has a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a function to run an if statement only if something has no value.

```
<script src="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/lib/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkNSC() {
        var confirmNSC = $("#SelectNsc");
        if (confirmNSC.length == 0) {
            alert("Please ensure all required fields are filled out")
        }
        else {
            alert("NSC has value")
        }

    }

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="SelectNsc" />
<button onclick="checkNSC();" id="myButton">My Button</button>
</div>
```

I'm trying to say if the value is 0 then to display an alert saying (Please ensure all fields are filled out". Otherwise say "NSC has a value"

Thanks,

Comment: With `var confirmNSC = $("#SelectNsc");` you get a reference to the DOM element (in your case the input), but NOT the value of the input. To get the value of the input, use `$("#SelectNsc").val()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be,

```
var confirmNSC = $("#SelectNsc").val();
```

Because `$("#SelectNsc")` return a jquery object, so that `$("#SelectNsc").length` will always return a value greater than 0.

```
<script src = "https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/lib/jquery-1.11.1.js" > < /script> 
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
      var confirmNSC = $("#SelectNsc").val().trim();
      if (confirmNSC.length == 0) {
        alert("Please ensure all required fields are filled out")
      } else {
        alert("NSC has value")
      }
    });

  })
</script>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5371/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, It's working fine

```html
<script src="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/lib/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkNSC() {
        var confirmNSC = $("#SelectNsc");
        if (confirmNSC.val() =='') {
            alert("Please ensure all required fields are filled out")
        }
        else {
            alert("NSC has value")
        }

    }

</script>


<input type="text" id="SelectNsc" />
<button onclick="checkNSC();" id="myButton">My Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code :

```
<body>
 <script src="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/lib/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkNSC() {
        var confirmNSC = document.getElementById("SelectNsc").value;
        if (confirmNSC.length == 0) {
            alert("Please ensure all required fields are filled out")
        }
        else {
            alert("NSC has value")
        }

    }

</script>
    <input type="text" id="SelectNsc" />
<button onclick="checkNSC();" id="myButton">My Button</button>
</body>
```

OR , use this code :

```
<body>
 <script src="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/lib/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkNSC() {
        var confirmNSC = $("#SelectNsc").val();
        if (confirmNSC.length == 0) {
            alert("Please ensure all required fields are filled out")
        }
        else {
            alert("NSC has value")
        }

    }

</script>
    <input type="text" id="SelectNsc" />
<button onclick="checkNSC();" id="myButton">My Button</button>
</body>
```